# Transferring data from input to output File, getting Exception

Tags: java, file, fileinputstream, file-writing

My data is not getting transferred to the output file , I always get an `Exception`.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class TransferData {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       String path1="E:\\IO\\Input.txt";
       String path2="E:\\IO\\Output.txt";
       int data;
       System.out.println("Transfering started...");
       try {
           FileInputStream  fis=new FileInputStream(path1);
           FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(path2);
           while((data=fis.read())!=-1) {
               fos.write(data);
           }
       }
       catch(Exception e) {
           System.out.println("exception caught!");
       }
       System.out.println("Completed...");
    }
}
```

How do I transfer data to output file ?

Comment: **What** Exception? Can you provide a StackTrace please?

Comment: Exception caught ! message appears

Comment: Add `e.printStackTrace()` to the `catch` block and post the message that appears.

Answer (score 2):

Tested this code on my local machine it is works without exceptions.

1. Check is file **E:/IO/Input.txt exists**.
2. IS Directory **E:/IO is writeable** for your user
   (If file **E:/IO/Output.txt already exists check is it writeable** and not opened in another programm)

By code:
It is good practice to close FIS and FOS after programm finished execution.

```
public class TransferData {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      String path1 = "E:\\IO\\Input.txt";
      String path2 = "E:\\IO\\Output.txt";
      int data;
      System.out.println("Transfering started...");
      FileInputStream fis = null;
      FileOutputStream fos = null;
      try {
         fis = new FileInputStream(path1);
         fos = new FileOutputStream(path2);
         while ((data = fis.read()) != -1) {
            fos.write(data);
         }
      } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      } finally {
         try {
            if (fis != null) {
               fis.close();
            }
            if (fos != null) {
               fos.close();
            }
         } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }

      }
      System.out.println("Completed...");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you replace `System.out.println("exception caught!");` with `e.printStackTrace();` then you will get a much more useful error message.

If you then post that error message here, people will be able to help you much more easily.

---

It could be the case that the program cannot find the file you're trying to read.

Answer (score 1):

I highly suggest to use `e.printStackTrace()` as the others suggested.

One possible problem might be the filesystem permissions or the file you are trying to read from being not existent.

You might also want to use a ["*try with resources*"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to simplify your code.
Your code is missing a `close` statement for your Streams too.

All together your code would look something like this:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class TransferData {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String path1="E:\\IO\\Input.txt";
        String path2="E:\\IO\\Output.txt";
        int data;
        System.out.println("Transfering started...");
        try (
            FileInputStream  fis=new FileInputStream(path1);
            FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(path2)
        ) {
            while((data=fis.read())!=-1) {
                fos.write(data);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

One last thing, if you post your code on StackOverflow, please do **not** mix different formatting styles (e.g. `{` in the same line as an `if` and sometimes in the next) and try to have the code well formatted from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Add `e.printStackTrace()` to your `catch` block, and post the data printed in your console here, people will be able to help you better.

---

The most likely cause of the exception getting thrown is that the system is not able to find the file `"E:\\IO\\Input.txt"` or `"E:\\IO\\Output.txt"` make sure that the file's are there and `Output.txt` is not set to read only.